How can I change VS Code Markdown code-formatted text colour?
My VS Code editor's Markdown inline code blocks have the same foreground and background colour. How should I change this?
The foreground and background is white
I checked all my settings and it does not have any modifications to the theme besides the high contrast theme i selected. Furthermore i have been trying to modify the "editor.tokenColorCustomizations": of my editor in the settings.json of my VS Code.
When I change to other themes, the background is not the same and is readable
The background and foreground is different

You want this in settings.json:
"workbench.colorCustomizations": {
    "textPreformat.foreground": "#ff0000", // TODO. for inline code
    "textPreformat.background": "#ff0000", // TODO. for inline code
    "textCodeBlock.background": "#ff0000", // TODO. for code blocks
},

But this probably some sort of theme bug Illegible textPreformat in dark high contrast theme vscode 1.90.0 #214412 so I suggest you wait for the fix to be released.
